# Adding a image to a docx with python - pandas (.csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, docx

This is my actual code(if it serves as context), i want to replace my word text {{image}} to an actual image, im really new programing and i know there is probably a very easy solution

```
    from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
    import pandas as pd 

    doc = DocxTemplate("plantilla-mi-info.docx")

    df = pd.read_csv('fake_data.csv')


   for index, row in df.iterrows():
      context = {'a': row['a'],
                'b': row['b'],     
         } #etc

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(f"descargo_{index}.docx")`
```

`

i try to add to context

'image.jpeg': row['image']

but of course only replaces with text 'image.jpeg'

If u want to send me back to watch Python for Beginners - Learn Python in 10 Hours, do it xd

Comment: Have a look at the [`docxtpl` > Inline Image](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inline-image) docs; images need to be constructed as a `docxtpl.InlineImage` object (see [the example](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/inline_image.py)).
See also the section on [multiple rendering](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-rendering); I believe your `doc.render` call needs to be indented inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @JOSHUAVOSKAMP thx bro, really glad for your answer